# Rules/guidelines for email to activity processing?

Tags: activity, inbound-email

CiviCRM 5.45.6, Drupal 7.  Client is using email to activity processing but is having intermittent failures with it.  I've reviewed the Civi docs and while they explain how to set up the functionality, there appear to be no real guidelines re whether to forward versus CC versus BCC, whether there is a limit on the number of contacts who can be included in the activity creation, and so forth.  Are there specific guidelines somewhere, or even guidance based on your previous experience with the functionality?  Any help/tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database is utf8 you can get failures with emojis in emails. I recommend utf8mb4 anyway for other reasons.

There's no known limit on contacts.

If you're using the method where you're cc'ing or forwarding to a dedicated email I usually recommend bcc because otherwise it gets harvested and it eventually ends up on spam lists. Similarly don't advertise it publicly. And name it something unusual that wouldn't get randomly hit, like civicrm_email_processor@example.com.

I don't really see a difference between forward and cc/bcc. When initially sending an email, you'd want to include the other recipients because otherwise it will only attach it to your own contact in civi. But if you've already received an email and want to file it, then forwarding to the email processor is the most straightforward way. There is also the other method where you have a separate civi mail account pointed at a folder in your mailbox, and then you can just drag received emails into that folder to file them in civi and autoattach to the other contacts, but then you need to put your personal mail password in civi.

Also note if using Cases then you can put `[case #1234]` in the subject and it will attach it to case 1234. I also recommend https://civicrm.org/extensions/replace-or-remove-case-hash-email-subject if you're using civi this way.